# Manipulate List to return Map

Tags: java-8, java-stream

**Objective:** `List<User>` for each User dto I want to return only *id* and *name*

Format should be like:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "ruben"
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": null
 }
]
```

**My Attempt:**

```
List<Users> userList = null;
    Map<String, String> resultMap=new HashMap<>();
    try {
        userList = userRepository.findAllUserTitle();
        userList.parallelStream().forEach(p->{

            resultMap.put("id", String.valueOf(p.getId()));
            resultMap.put("title", p.getTitle());
        });
```

**Note:** Is it possible to achieve this using streams flatmaps or any other solution please provide also I don't want to create any other dto.

Comment: `users.stream().map(User::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @HadiJ I said both id and name to be returned in map

Comment: The question is unclear and there is no attempt from you.

Comment: @Nikolas added attempted code and the problem in that is it's not returning like I wanted
in json object

Comment: `resultMap = userList.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (h, u) -> h.put(String.valueOf(u.getId()), u.getTitle()), (h1,h2) -> h1.putAll(h2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *map* (i.e. transform) each `User` dto to an object that only has the `id` and `name` attributes:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = userRepository.findAllUserTitle().stream()
    .map(u -> {
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("id", u.getId());
        m.put("name", u.getName());
        return m;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I've transformed each user dto to a `HashMap` instance, then I collected these maps to a list of maps.

If you are on Java 9+, you could achieve the same with less code:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = userRepository.findAllUserTitle().stream()
    .map(u -> Map.of("id", u.getId(), "name", u.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

NOTE: Most times, using parallel streams has no benefit. On the contrary, it is slower

Comment: It looks good but the problem is I wrote native query when I do `findAllUserTitle()` and it return `List<Object>` so if its okay then I can call User as a generic type in List but if you have solution in my case then I would be more delighted although your answer looks perfect to me since I don't want to change code can you provide the solution that way around?

Comment: @Kramer That's another problem, a different one, not related to your original question. Your query must be returning a list of maps. Use a debugger and inspect the runtime type of the elements of the list. I'm pretty sure it already is a map of string to object. Or use Spring/Hibernate (or whatever you are using) correctly, so that the query returns the exact Dto you want

Comment: when I write native query and pick only two property like id and title then it says that property x not found where 'x' can be any property in the dto therefore need to take type as `java.lang.Object` or I can do it in your way which seems to me the only solution slso eklavya solution is same as yours

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are using the same map for every user that is the problem.

Use  `List<Map<String, String>>` where `Map<String, String>` represent per user `id` and `name` data

```
List<Map<String, String>> result=new ArrayList<>(); // Create a list of map for result
List<Users> userList= userRepository.findAllUserTitle();
userList.stream().forEach(p->{
    Map<String, String> resultMap=new HashMap<>();
    resultMap.put("id", String.valueOf(p.getId()));
    resultMap.put("title", p.getTitle());
    result.add(resultMap); // for every user info map add in list.
});
```